# Is there anyway to communicate a type backwards through a chain from final return to parameter of a previous chain method? (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types

The below code works it just doesn't have as much type inference as I would wish (so in that regard at least it doesn't work completely as expected). Also, the above may be a weird and slightly dense title for the question, but basically I want two things that I'm not even sure if TypeScript can accomplish.

First, I want the final return type of the below chain to be a function whose return type we'll call `T` as what I'm expecting as the parameter to the first occurrence of `modifyReturn` in the given chain. As an example the type below of `returnValue1` below should be `T`.

Secondly, I want a similar effect with the first call in the chain to `modifyArgs` in that I want its params to be the expected params of what we'll call the type `FinalResolver` which should be the function that is returned from resolve (which then ends up terminating the chain) to match the params/arguments of the function first in the chain for `modifyArgs`.  For example the below a,b,c,d in the first modifyArgs should be basically of type `Parameters<FinalResolver>` which ends up being {}, {}, {db: any, response: any, request: any}, {}.

In other words (and much more briefly) first, I would like for the left hand side of the equal signs IResolver in the below code to determine the validity of the types of the first `modifyArgs` arguments, so a,b,c,d should be {}, {}, {db: any, response: any, request: any}, {} respectively. Second, I would like the return value of the resolve function to determine the type of the first `modifyReturn`'s param.

This is how the type is used (really this shouldn't have to be changed [just here as an example usage]):

```
const temp: IResolver<{}, {}, {db: any, response: any, request: any}, {}, "baz">  = ResolveChain().modifyArgs((a,b,c,d /* should be (I'll use 'should be' to show that it's currently not working) {},{},{db: any, response: any, request: any}, {}, but is currently  */) => {
  return [1,2,3,4] as const;
}).modifyArgs(async (e,f,g,h /*is type (I'll use 'is type' to show it does work as intended) 1,2,3,4*/) => {
  return [2,3,4,5] as const;
}).modifyReturn((returnValue1 /* should be 'foo' (T as explained above), but is currently any */) => {
  return 'bar' as const;
}).modifyReturn((returnValue2 /* is type 'bar'*/) => {
  return 'baz' as const;
}).resolve((foo, bar, baz, qux /* is type 2,3,4,5 */) => {
  return 'foo'; // this return value is T
}); /* is type (root: {}, args: {}, context: {db: any, response: any, request: any}, {}) => 'baz' */
```

My utility types (this probably doesn't need to change either):

```
type IResolver<Root, Args, Context, Info, Return = any> = (root: Root, args: Args, context: Context, info: Info) => Return;

type If<Condition,TrueConditionType,FalseConditionType> = Condition extends true ? TrueConditionType : FalseConditionType;
```

The main type in question that I would like to fix to give me the two above properties is this one:

```
/** Allows one to chain and modify arguments and return values for a resolver. Arguments are modified before the resolver is called and return values are modified after. */
type ResolverChain<T, FinalResolver extends IResolver<any, any, any, any, T> =  IResolver<any, any, any, any>, ArgsResolver extends IResolver<any, any, any, any> =  IResolver<any, any, any, any>, IsFirst extends boolean = true> =  FinalResolver extends IResolver<infer FinalRoot, infer FinalArgs, infer FinalContext, infer FinalInfo, infer FinalReturn> ? If<IsFirst, IResolver<FinalRoot, FinalArgs, FinalContext, FinalInfo>, ArgsResolver> extends IResolver<infer Root, infer Args, infer Context, infer Info, infer Return> ? {
  /** This allows you to modify and change the type of the arguments being passed into the resolver. You can also throw an error if an argument is not
   * provided or if given the arguments you can tell the User is not authorized.
   */
  modifyArgs<NewRoot, NewArgs, NewContext, NewInfo>(resolveArgs: IResolver<Root, Args, Context, Info, readonly [NewRoot, NewArgs, NewContext, NewInfo] | Promise<readonly [NewRoot, NewArgs, NewContext, NewInfo]>>): ResolverChain<T, FinalResolver, IResolver<NewRoot, NewArgs, NewContext, NewInfo>, false>;
  /** This allows you to change the return value of the resolve function after the resolver has been called (each subsequent call to modify return will be run in the order it is added).
   * You can always throw to prevent the user from seeing something unauthorized or return null to prevent only the single field from being accessed.
   */
  modifyReturn<NewReturn extends T>(resolveArgs: (resolverReturn: FinalReturn) => NewReturn): ResolverChain<T, IResolver<FinalRoot, FinalArgs, FinalContext, FinalInfo, NewReturn>, ArgsResolver, false>;
  /** This will resolve the chain into a compatible resolver function. */
  resolve(resolver: IResolver<Root, Args, Context, Info, T>): FinalResolver;
} : never : never;
```

Finally here's the implementation if you want to dig into how this function works better though it should most likely not need to be changed to answer the question:

**Edited** from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64597395/is-there-anyway-to-communicate-a-type-backwards-through-a-chain-from-final-retur?noredirect=1#comment114225115_64597395)

```
/** */
function ResolveChain <T>(argResolvers: IResolver<any, any, any, any>[] = [], returnResolvers: ((arg:T) => T)[] = []): ResolverChain<T> {
  return {
    modifyArgs (fn) {
      return ResolveChain([...argResolvers, fn], returnResolvers);
    },
    modifyReturn (fn) {
      return ResolveChain(argResolvers, [...returnResolvers, fn]);
    },
    resolve (resolveFn) {
      return async (...args) => {
        for(const fn of argResolvers) {
          args = await fn(...args);
        }
        let returnValue = await resolveFn(...args);
        for(const fn of returnResolvers) {
          returnValue = await fn(returnValue);
        }
        return returnValue;
      };
    }
  }
}
```

If you noticed I tried and failed to fix the above two problems with the `IsFirst` generic used as a flag in combination with the `If` type (If<IsFirst, IResolver<FinalRoot, FinalArgs, FinalContext, FinalInfo>, ArgsResolver>) I made in order to set whether the function should get it's type from the previous chained resolver (`ArgsResolver`) or the `FinalResolver`. (I believe I will end up needing two flags and likely to `If`s if the flag idea ends up working)

**Link edited** to reflect [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64597395/is-there-anyway-to-communicate-a-type-backwards-through-a-chain-from-final-retur?noredirect=1#comment114225115_64597395):

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-qc4bY3qzQldMzyzrXPE9M3tbxfe2m+gW7wVDEtI3OxXeCkDCyO-2u1lYfZlqwiqw03EM1pjXGzQOvFoBz2wAOhxFNV3Jynff7iPYg0brw2Z5429O+7igq-mSfYp-0JPe8y87KIuYAAN7UE6pwrM8rJWBc1yzAwKBzI8op-ACEJPK8yhyLS9ytGAiC6HMdKAnIwKgrMVIJHIYBMJYXA9JCCQPCR9JVjKSDIE8RZdDwJEuFcHyBqgLjoH8wm+OR+JZrByjiBBTrgEwLj8HEeCQog4nEXIcSCKYdCkVJFEEmASHceyBm4BcbFgAAqj04mzPJWaWMghlaXEABe5JYopsqKWh-y+kIAByuBXHuUjhVch4xd+WgxRezhVr6yQPiIL6HglUj-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-usmEqTULBAKkOTL+HhHAf3kG4Koad7BwKAQ4IBOdFqqhWg6MCC8s6fXAlzEm6FfROF0ModIeD8EGz5NeF+jgSpYnoZ-DiigAbKAamAnBygv6pAulzQ+Eh-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-AzhXAeDNb4njeynHDh40cy1eLbWiYdYiJ1NhHk2LA+8gKtAeWLKWe0NAkN0AAGU1BMFmCpuA89QCKXsJp14RJzLoEZO5Jo39nh0DoLptwwBgBgheFiAAVlwLEWk5DAEDes4A1guBXGIMZsAcSyRCSs+MWz9nHPOdc88DzXmfN+YC9FmzYWACyWl8BLSRjhbgHg7MOf8AlrgbnPPefkNQee1AgA)

Comment: Is this a [mcve] for your problem? There's just so much going on in this code and every time I try to break it into pieces the compiler performance tanks and so I haven't even gotten to the point of seeing the issue. My recommendation is to *simplify this* into something that has an inference issue but doesn't have so many moving parts. Sounds like you want contextual typing through a chain of method calls, but even in ideal situations this is tough. I'm not surprised to see contextual inference failures through chained conditional types... but without a more minimal example, ‍♂️.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and add an edit ! I'll try making a minimal example I'm not sure how exactly I would go about that at the moment, but I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: I too am unable to comprehend this, but I can tell you that you need to be setting default generic values on `modifyArgs`.  `NewArgs`, `NewContext`, and `NewInfo` are inferred by the arguments that the function is called with, but in your examples you don't use these arguments so there is nothing to infer.  If we want to keep the current generics for the next type in the chain, we need to default to the current type.  Though I really don't understand where these values actually come into play.

Comment: You've got some logic for how you create a resolver chain and some logic for how you execute the chain.  It might help to separate those two things and to take an OOP approach (look into the command pattern and the builder pattern).

Comment: Well you're not alone in not understanding this completely. I understand what my problem is, but I'm pretty sure I am missing something and overcomplicating this quite a bit (there's probably extraneous types there). If you are wondering what the purpose of this function does It's for GraphQL, and the implementation could probably clear up in what order they run. So, would the OOP approach work with just the pure types (like applying some type patterns) or would I have to restructure my code? I'm still working on trying to split up problem one and two as far as types go.

Comment: It's also very heavily relying on what I learned from this type challenge https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/master/questions/12-medium-chainable-options/README.md

Comment: That challenge is a breeze compared to this!  `type Chainable<T = {}> = {
  option<K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V): Chainable<T & {[Key in K]: V}>
  get(): T
}`.  OOP would mean rewriting the whole thing.  Are you saying that the function is fine, and it's just the types that need work?  Also inside of `resolve()` you call all of the arg resolvers before any of the return resolvers.  I would have expected functions to get called as they are added, with each getting the args as it exists at the point where they are added.

Comment: "Are you saying that the function is fine, and it's just the types that need work?" Yes the function is just how I want it. "Also inside of resolve() you call all of the arg resolvers before any of the return resolvers. I would have expected functions to get called as they are added, with each getting the args as it exists at the point where they are added" Yes that is fine. I am using it so that each call flows through the modifyArgs then they flow through the resolve function then finally the return value goes through each of the return functions.

Comment: The main reason for the modifyArgs is to add composable authorization checks (possibly throwing an error if auth fails) and add additional attributes to the resolver before it gets to the resolve function. Then the purpose of the modifyReturn is to add authorization checks (which when they fail either return null or throw an error) or to modify the result of the resolve function before it reaches the consumer of the GraphQL API.

Comment: The way that you are storing the `argResolvers` (same for `returnResolvers`) in an array makes it hard (impossible?) to properly type them.  The values of `Root`, `Context`, and `Info` are the same for every element so that's not a problem.  The problem is that `Args` changes for each element.  For each element in the array, the input depends on the output of the previous element, and that's not something that you can do in TS.  If this is working and you don't want to go back to the drawing board, so some `as` assertions and call it a day.

Comment: OMG, I messed up the function haha, but the question is still the same regardless. So, I did mess up the functionality in that I meant for each returnValue to be the one and only one parameter to the returnResolvers functions doh!

Answer (score 1):

You and I had a long discussion in the comments about some of the hurdles and limitations of the current approach, but I'm happy to say that I have some types for you!

On the execution side of things, the applying of the resolvers, we are not able to have strict types.  This is a limitation of the current implementation. We are storing arrays of resolvers and that doesn't allow us to enforce the necessary requirement that each element's return type becomes one of the input arguments for the next element.

But we can make major progress on the building side of things, where we add new resolvers and change our knowledge of the chain's types accordingly.  You were inspired by a particular [challenge problem](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/master/questions/12-medium-chainable-options/README.md) to create a chainable type that updates the return type for its final `get()` call after each `option()` method call.  My [solution](https://tsplay.dev/oN92Mm) to that challenge is this:

```
interface Chainable<T = {}> {
  option<K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V): Chainable<T & {[Key in K]: V}>
  get(): T
}
```

With each call to `option` we infer generic values `K` and `V` based on the values of the function arguments.  We return an object which still has the same `interface Chainable` but has an updated generic value reflecting the changes.

We will apply that same principle to your case but with more generics -- six of them!  We have a variable `Args` that changes with each call to `modifyArgs` and a variable `Value` that changes with each call to `modifyReturn`.  But when we finally resolve to a result by calling `resolve()` at the end of the chain, we are going to provide it with a value and args from the types that we started with, so we need to store those types.  I have called them `InitialValue` and `InitialArgs`.

```
function ResolveChain <Context, Info, InitialValue, InitialArgs = {}, Value = InitialValue, Args = InitialArgs>(...
```

The values for the mutable generics, `Value` and `Args`, need to go last in the list so that we can make them optional and have them start with their initial values. The other four types are expected to be declared when you call the function to create a chain.

Were you to structure your code differently so that the arguments for the "final return" were passed in at the start rather than at the end, we could infer types rather than having to declare them explicitly.

We call this function and create a `ResolverChain`.  I gave it the same types in the same order:

```
interface ResolverChain<Context, Info, InitialValue, InitialArgs = {}, Value = InitialValue, Args = InitialArgs> {
```

Our resolver chain `interface` needs to define three methods.  Both `modifyArgs` and `modifyReturn` will take a function and return a new `ResolverChain`.  I kept your definition for the function mostly the same.  I've stated that the return type can be either a `Promise` or a value, which cleans things up a lot.

```
type Resolver<Value, Args, Context, Info, Return> = (
    value: Value, args: Args, context: Context, info: Info
) => Return | Promise<Return>;
```

The function that we pass to `modifyArgs` takes the four standard arguments and returns a new type for args: `NewArgs`.  The **only** generic that we need to infer here is the return type `NewArgs`.  This function should act on the current args value `Args`, but because you call all of your `argResolvers` before any of your `returnResolvers` it receives `InitialValue` rather than `Value`.

The `ResolverChain` that we return has one of its generics changed.  We replace `Args` with `NewArgs` and keep all the rest.

```
modifyArgs<NewArgs>(
    resolveArgs: Resolver<InitialValue, Args, Context, Info, NewArgs>
): ResolverChain<Context, Info, InitialValue, InitialArgs, Value, NewArgs>;
```

`modifyReturn` does the same thing, but for `Value`.  Our resolver return type gets inferred as `NewValue` and we return a chain with `NewValue` in place of `Value`.

There is one potential bug here which is a limitation of the current design.  We know that all `returnResolvers` will be called with the final value of `Args` but when cannot possibly know what that type will be when we are still able to change it by calling `modifyArgs`.  When creating your chain, you should make all calls to `modifyArgs` before `modifyReturn` in order to get the correct `Args` type.

How about we force the methods to be called in the proper order?  When we return a chain from `modifyReturn`, we simply `Omit` the `modifyArgs` method.  It is still present at runtime, but typescript doesn't know about it so we will get errors if we call `modifyArgs` after `modifyReturn`.

```
modifyReturn<NewValue>(
    resolveArgs: Resolver<Value, Args, Context, Info, NewValue>
): Omit<ResolverChain<Context, Info, InitialValue, InitialArgs, NewValue, Args>, 'modifyArgs'>;
```

For the final `resolve()`, it doesn't make sense to me that we would pass it a function. If we want to mofify it, we can do that by calling `modifyReturn` right before. I wrote what makes sense to me, which is that we give it four values, the `InitialValue` and `InitialArgs` along with the immutable `Context` and `Info`, and expect it to return the current type of `Value`.

```
resolve: Resolver<InitialValue, InitialArgs, Context, Info, Value>;
```

The implementation cannot be perfectly typed, as I explained earlier. But here's the best we can do.

`argResolvers` needs `any` for `Args` and `Return` since these vary, while `returnResolvers` needs `any` for `Value`, `Args`, and `Return`.

```
(
  argResolvers: Resolver<InitialValue, any, Context, Info, any>[] = [], 
  returnResolvers: Resolver<any, any, Context, Info, any>[] = []
)
```

Our `resolve` is now an `aysnc` method which returns a `Promise` that resolves to the final `Value`.  Its `args` are four of the values from our generic, as explained previously.

```
async resolve (...args: [InitialValue, InitialArgs, Context, Info]): Promise<Value> {
```

```
async resolve (initialValue: InitialValue, initialArgs: InitialArgs, context: Context, info: Info): Promise<Value> {
```

For the values that we modify, those variables are going to start with their initial type.  Typescript does not expect or allow that type to change, so in order to have the correct final type, we have to tell typescript to shut up.  I told you the implementation was not ideal!

```
let args = initialArgs as unknown as Args;
let value = initialValue as unknown as Value;
```

Putting it all together we get:

```
type Resolver<Value, Args, Context, Info, Return> = (
  value: Value, args: Args, context: Context, info: Info
) => Return | Promise<Return>;

interface ResolverChain<Context, Info, InitialValue, InitialArgs = {}, Value = InitialValue, Args = InitialArgs> {

  modifyArgs<NewArgs>(
    resolveArgs: Resolver<InitialValue, Args, Context, Info, NewArgs>
  ): ResolverChain<Context, Info, InitialValue, InitialArgs, Value, NewArgs>;

  modifyReturn<NewValue>(
    resolveArgs: Resolver<Value, Args, Context, Info, NewValue>
  ): Omit<ResolverChain<Context, Info, InitialValue, InitialArgs, NewValue, Args>, 'modifyArgs'>;

  resolve: Resolver<InitialValue, InitialArgs, Context, Info, Value>;
};

function ResolveChain<Context, Info, InitialValue, InitialArgs = {}, Value = InitialValue, Args = InitialArgs>(
  argResolvers: Resolver<InitialValue, any, Context, Info, any>[] = [],
  returnResolvers: Resolver<any, any, Context, Info, any>[] = []
): ResolverChain<Context, Info, InitialValue, InitialArgs, Value, Args> {
  return {
    modifyArgs(fn) {
      return ResolveChain([...argResolvers, fn], returnResolvers);
    },
    modifyReturn(fn) {
      return ResolveChain(argResolvers, [...returnResolvers, fn]);
    },
    async resolve(initialValue: InitialValue, initialArgs: InitialArgs, context: Context, info: Info): Promise<Value> {
      let args = initialArgs as unknown as Args;
      for (const fn of argResolvers) {
        args = await fn(initialValue, args, context, info);
      }
      let value = initialValue as unknown as Value;
      for (const fn of returnResolvers) {
        value = await fn(value, args, context, info);
      }
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

Play around with the various callbacks on the [Typescript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Lw6eRW):

```
const temp2 = ResolveChain<{ db: any, response: any, request: any }, {}, 'baz', {initialArgument: number}>()
  .modifyArgs((root, args) => ({
    ...args,
    hello: "world",
  }))
  .modifyReturn((ret) => ({ key: ret }))
  .modifyReturn((ret, args) => ({
    ...ret,
    fromArgs: args.hello + args.initialArgument,
  }))
  .resolve('baz', {initialArgument: 5}, { db: "", response: "", request: "" }, {});
  // resolves to { fromArgs: string; key: "baz"; }
```

**note:**

This might not be exactly what you intended.  I didn't see your change from `returnValue = await fn(...args)` to `returnValue = await fn(returnValue)` until after I started writing this.  I remain highly confused in the section on `argResolvers` whether `args` refers to the second of four arguments or to the array of all four, since you seem to be using it as both simultaneously.  So modify this code as you need to.

Comment: This is very close. I feel very bad for confusing you so bad with the edits (that's my mistake) as they were mixed in with the content and I did a poor job of updating them everywhere, but I definitely think this is about as close as I'll get to an answer. So, thank you very much I appreciate it greatly. Part of your writeup has given me a better way to reason about types already so I really do appreciate it.